# Remove big valley in phase plot

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, pid-controller, bode-plot

I am working on a speed controller for a robot and it's for when the robot is balancing on its wheels.
I am designing the controller as part of a project in a linear control design course. However, the controller has to be implemented on a robot and in software delivered by my instructor, so I don't have infinite room of freedom. The way I implement my controller can be seen here:-

[image]

As you can see, I can add a gain \$K_p \$, an integrator and post-integrator, a lead/lag-term in both forward and feedback path, a prefilter and a feed-forward. And that's it. I can't change what feedback I'm receiving, I can only add and adjust terms of the controller.

### Edit - Finding the new transfer function

Doing what AJN suggests gives me a much nicer bode plot:-

[image]

The bode plot is much nicer, but I still have some trouble. I want to smooth out the hill in the phase plot, but I am not sure how to do so.

The new transfer function:

```
num = [0 0 0 -3.5113e+07 -3.7165e+10 -2.0902e+12 -3.8701e+13 -1.5402e+14 2.5341e+15 2.2109e+16 3.3405e+16];
den = [1 2.4731e+03 1.4491e+06 2.5930e+08 1.2622e+10 9.9503e+10 -1.8488e+12 -1.0302e+13 0 0 0];
G2 = tf(num,den);
```

### Earlier form of the question containing some outdated info

```
num = [0 0 0 0 -2.3409e+07 -2.4777e+10 -1.3935e+12 -2.5801e+13 -1.0268e+14 1.6894e+15 1.4740e+16 2.2270e+16];
den = [1 2.4738e+03 1.4508e+06 2.6223e+08 1.5442e+10 6.8736e+11 2.6563e+13 5.2944e+14 4.0900e+15 8.1300e+15 3.7708e+15 1.1220e+13];
G2 = tf(num,den);
```

The open and closed loop bode plot for the transfer function is here:-

[image]

As you can see in the closed loop bode plot, there is a big valley in the phase, and this causes the system to be unstable (I think), and I don't want that.

My inital idea was to add a lag-term to the forward path. A lag-term **removes** phase, so if I place it right where the valley is the peak should get smaller. My lag-term looks like this:-

[image]

But even after adding the lag-term the phase still looks very weird. Here is the new closed loop bode plot:-

[image]

Is there a way to remove this phase valley and get a proper stable system?

Comment: This looks like hysteresis induced resonances that cause the phase reversal. And reminds me of graduate inverted broom servo train thesis. This has been done many times. Eliminating the slack (hysteresis) with push or pull tension and a velocity and position feedback loop will give better results.

Comment: Using position control with the 2nd integral of current makes for poor phase margin. Try to use 1st order feedback, velocity arm angle  then Position of angle and vehicle.  I.e. multiple loops as the load changes with angle is nonlinear

Comment: I plotted the poles and zeros of the plant and noticed; a zero on the RHP and two complex conjugate poles on the RHP. The system will be quite difficult to stabilize as you need to bring the poles to the RHP while keeping the open loop poles from migrating towards the RHP zero in the loop closing process.

Comment: "*As you can see in the **closed** loop bode plot, there is a big valley in the phase, and this causes the system to be unstable (I think), and I don't want that.*" The phase plot of the closed loop plot may not be the way to think about this problem.

Comment: "*I have found the transfer function between the robot tilt angle and the wheel velocity.*" How did you find it ? System identification based on some test input and output. Or first principles mathematical modelling ?

Comment: @AJN I have added an explanation to my question.

Comment: Perhaps I do not fully understand the simulink diagram, but why are there two lines feeding back from *tilt_angle*; viz., a blue highlighted line and an other line which seems to feed into *ref_tilt*. Wouldn't *ref_tilt* be a predefined signal like a step input or something similar? I do not have much experience linearising systems in simulink.

Comment: Was the loop break and monitoring points defined in `ios` given to you; or did you decide those loop break points your self ?

Comment: I would have cut the loop just just after the summing junction where the blue line attaches to get open loop `G(s)H(s)` and not have the topmost feedback line at all in the diagram.

Comment: @AJN I did what you suggested and it resulted in a "nicer" bode plot. I guess I must have found the transfer function wrongly initially.

Comment: this looks more reasonable. however, be careful! I dont know how simulink works, but you may be plotting `-G(s)H(s)` now. Simulink doesn't know that it has to ignore the `-ve` sign in the summing junction when opening a loop (At least older simulink version didn't; I think). The positive shape of the phase plot makes me believe that to be the case. Be cautious.

Comment: @AJN Although I am now working with the proper transfer function, I'm still having trouble designing my controller because I'm not sure which way to go. My only thought was to smooth out the phase plot by adding a lag-term at the hill. But it doesn't turn out the way I want. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123183/discussion-between-ajn-and-carl).

Answer (score 1):

A good part of Engineering Design is trying not to reinvent the wheel and learn from other’s past mistakes and make improvements.  There are many non-linear factors not included in your simulation such as hysteresis from friction and slack in every moving part and a lack of design specs for inputs and output error.  A single step response to voltage is not the best test as motor BEMF changes the torque.

- use Current control and feedback for smooth acceleration/braking rather than step voltage.
- To accelerate an inverted arm, you must go backwards first to tilt the arm forward then accelerate enough at peak velocity to tilt the arm backwards in preparation for braking towards target position.
- research the conclusions of a dozen similar yet different inverted broom or pendulum thesis papers and cite the flaws and solutions you propose with multiple loops for ideal acceleration, velocity, tilt angle and horizontal position with errors and tolerances allowed.
- [Here](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/20288/1/V%20Sonic_Inverted%20Pendulum%20Demonstrator.pdf) is one example that met some criteria yet failed in the end to be robust. Read the conclusions of each paper first and follow my advice. The contents will give you some insights to theory but be incomplete.